# Match SKU with Product ID and is_in_stock

Tags: database

I am trying to get a table that displays:

**SKU**

**product_id**

**is_in_stock**

I got this which displays SKU and Product ID in a table and I want to add is_in_stock to it, I got this:

```
SELECT entity_id as product_id, sku FROM catalog_product_entity;
```

catalog_product_entity table:

[image]

I need to add is_in_stock column now from table `cataloginventory_stock_item`, this table holds the product ID column.

[image]

How can I do that?

This is my output, I need to add a column is_in_stock to it from different table but am struggling:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT p.entity_id as product_id, p.sku, c.is_in_stock 
FROM catalog_product_entity as p
INNER JOIN cataloginventory_stock_item as c 
ON p.entity_id = c.product_id
```

then if you want to create a new table

```
CREATE TABLE table_name
SELECT p.entity_id as product_id, p.sku, c.is_in_stock 
FROM catalog_product_entity as p
INNER JOIN cataloginventory_stock_item as c 
ON p.entity_id = c.product_i
```

You can use different types of joins left, right outer.
See more info here https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you kindly, I will do my homework on that topic :)